# C - Does strcpy have any special properties to it?

Tags: c, binary-tree, strcpy

Every time I attempt to insert a string into a binary tree in my program, I have to use `strcpy` and use the `strcpy`'s destination for it to insert successfully. If I do not use `strcpy` and use just the source, it will crash the program.

Example:

```
char *originalstring;
originalstring = (char *)calloc(alloc + 1, sizeof(char));
originalstring = "Hello.";
insert(&root, originalstring); //into binary tree
```

Results in a crash.

```
char *newstring, *originalstring;

originalstring = (char *)calloc(alloc + 1, sizeof(char));
originalstring = "Hello.";

newstring = (char *)calloc(alloc + 1, sizeof(char));
strcpy(newstring, originalstring);

insert(&root, newstring);
```

Inserts it into the tree. My full program is of course significantly larger than this, but I really don't think it has anything to do with me being forced to use a `strcpy` to insert a string. This leads me to asking whether or not `strcpy` has special things.

Edit: I have also attempted to manually nullbyte the end of `originalstring` and that has failed.

Comment: You are not showing us enough to know exactly, but if your code would be trying to write into a `"string literal"`, yes, this may crash your execution, and rightly so.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt could you elaborate further please? Both `newstring` and `originalstring` are the exact same, are they not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
originalstring = (char *)calloc(alloc + 1, sizeof(char));
originalstring = "Hello.";
```

you are firstly allocating some storage for a string, which is fine, but then in the second line you are replacing the pointer to this storage with a pointer to a string literal. The original allocation has then been "lost" (resulting in a memory leak), and if you try to modify the contents of `originalString` you will get undefined behaviour, since you're now pointing at what is most likely read-only memory. You will also get undefined behaviour if you subsequently try to `free` this string (since it was not allocated via `malloc`).

So, bottom line: always use `strcpy` to copy strings - only ever use direct assignment (`=`) when manipulating pointers to strings.

---

Some additional notes on coding style:

- [never cast the result of malloc in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) - it's unnecessary and potentially dangerous
- `sizeof(char)` is always equal to `1`, by definition

so the above allocation should really just be written as:

```
originalstring = calloc(alloc + 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assigned the string literal `"Hello."` to the pointer originalstring causes the pointer to point to that string literal,abandoning the allocated memory.this leads to crash in case you attempt to free this pointer or modify the string literal.